# How can I write an angular directive to listen to changes in `ngOptions`?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using the [angular-bootstrap-select](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select/blob/master/src/angular-bootstrap-select.js#L145) plugin to style selects. It is basically a port of the `bootstrap-select` plugin that hooks into angular.

As of right now it seems to update whenever the `ng-model` changes. However I would also like to listen to the `ng-options`

Here is the relevant part of the plugin:

```js
angular.module('angular-bootstrap-select', [])
  .directive('selectpicker', ['$parse', '$timeout', selectpickerDirective]);

function selectpickerDirective($parse, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1000,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      function refresh(newVal) {
        scope.$applyAsync(function () {
          if (attrs.ngOptions && /track by/.test(attrs.ngOptions)) element.val(newVal);
          element.selectpicker('refresh');
        });
      }

      attrs.$observe('spTheme', function (val) {
        $timeout(function () {
          element.data('selectpicker').$button.removeClass(function (i, c) {
            return (c.match(/(^|\s)?btn-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
          });
          element.selectpicker('setStyle', val);
        });
      });

      $timeout(function () {
        element.selectpicker($parse(attrs.selectpicker)());
        element.selectpicker('refresh');
      });

      if (attrs.ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, refresh, true);
      }

      if (attrs.ngDisabled) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngDisabled, refresh, true);
      }

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $timeout(function () {
          element.selectpicker('destroy');
        });
      });
    }
  };
}
```

An example of the usage:

```
<select selectpicker ng-options="myOpt.key as myOpt.name for myOpt in myOpts" ng-model="myOptSelection"></select>
```

So I would like to edit the plugin to listen to changes in `myOpts` and run `element.refresh()`

Answer (score 0):

So far the best way I found was to insert the following into the plugin:

```
  if (attrs.ngOptions) {
    var watch = attrs.ngOptions.match(/in ([A-z0-9]+)$/);
    if (watch) {
      scope.$watch(watch[1], refresh, true);
    }
  }
```

Seems a little dirty though...I'm pretty new to angular, so I'm not sure what other possibilities there are for `ngOptions` or if there is a cleaner way to parse it.